# Replace default error message in type conversion for Web Api 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a RESTful service created in Web Api 2.2 (C#)

The input for the method is the following:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] PaymentInput paymentInput)
```

and my PaymentInput object has the following property:

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\.]*$", ErrorMessage = "ProductId must be an integer")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

In any case, I receive a default error message instead of mine, I think because model validation is done first and than regular expression validation.

For eg.:

```
            "productId": helloworld,
```

returns:

```
{
"message": "The request is invalid."
"modelState": {
"paymentInput.productId": [2]
0:  "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: v. Path 'productId', line 6, position 30."
    -
}-
}
```

and the following case:

```
            "productId": "helloworld",
```

returns the same.

So, my question is:

**How can I change this message?**

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: The `RegularExpression` attribute will never do anything because regular expressions are only valid on strings, not on integers. The input will be parsed before it even is assigned to your model. If you want to validate the input with a custom message returned to the caller the way you have it than turn your int into a string and add a method to your model that returns the value parsed by int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PaymentInput {
    // [Required] //removed Required unless you want a different message if nothing is provided
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\.]+$", ErrorMessage = "ProductId must be an integer")] 
    // changed regex to + instead of * which forces it to have at least 1 passed in character
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public int GetProductId() { return int.Parse(ProductId); }
}
```

- This change will allow the user to pass in anything into ProductId.
- It will allow you to execute your regular expression on the ProductId value.
- It will allow you to return the error message in the `RegularExpression` attribute.

---

The only thing I would like to add is this, **Should you worry about changing the message?**

In my opinion the message is very clear, don't pass in a non number into productId. Validation should be done by the client to ensure this does not happen. If it does then present a user friendly error message also generated by the client. Personally I would not try to make the Web API pass back friendly error messages, its a PITA plus localization is not something it should be concerned with either (messages in different languages). Also now you have to change all your incoming parameters to string types and then do validation on them in your code and return custom error messages for each.

In short it would probably be best to:

- Leave the server code as it is, it is doing its job. It also means less coding you have to do on the server.
- Make sure the client validates the input to some degree before sending the message to the server. If this is an external API then write documentation or generate API documentation that can be used by the caller when writing their interface.
- Handle the exceptions and messages on the client.

Comment: Thanks Igor. My concerns are about security, this is an expose method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error msg says it all

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Since, ProductId type is int, so system would first try to parse the JSON value to an int and then would put any validation that you are putting. It is failing while parsing itself, so there is no question of any other validation being done on that.

I think if you change the type of ProductID to string and then your regular expression validation would fire up to validate the input string of correct format. Regular expressions are executed on strings and not integers.